# Android Studio Map setOnMarkerClickListener not working on a fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers

As you can read in the title I have a problem with the method setOnMarkerClickListener in the map which is in a fragment.
The markers appear but when I click on them, their title simply appears instead of the Toast that I show below.

I have tried different solutions but none have worked for me. I leave my code here. Any help is appreciated!

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public LocationListener locationListener;
    public LatLng userLatLong,mLatLong1,mLatLong2;
    public boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    public boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    public MarkerOptions mPosicion,m1,m2;
    public Marker marcadorPosicion,marcador1,marcador2;

    SupportMapFragment fragment;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
        fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);

        
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);


        //REAL TIME POSITION NTW
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                userLatLong = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                marcadorPosicion.remove();


                mPosicion=new MarkerOptions().position(userLatLong).title("Estas aqui");
                marcadorPosicion = mMap.addMarker(mPosicion);

                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLatLong));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLatLong, 15));

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };

        //Marcadores
        cargarMapa();


        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Marker Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
public void cargarMapa(){

        //Marcadores

        //Metemos las coordenadas de los monumentos
        mLatLong1= new LatLng(43.3233106, -3.1215395);//Foto_002
        mLatLong2= new LatLng(43.3483518, -3.1189326);//Foto_00       


        m1=new MarkerOptions().position(mLatLong1).title("Foto_002").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));//Foto_002
        marcador1 = mMap.addMarker(m1);

        m2=new MarkerOptions().position(mLatLong2).title("Foto_005").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));//Foto_005
        marcador2 = mMap.addMarker(m2);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. For some reason when performing the addLayerMap method to add a kml to the map, the onMarkerClick method gets totally blocked. If someone has a similar problem in the future, what I'm doing is creating a route with Polyline with their respective coordinate points.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused due to the fact you are returning false on the onclicklistener. According to the documentation returning false makes the default option of opening the info window.

So You could do something like

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
              if (marker.getTitle().equals("Foto_002") || marker.getTitle().equals("Foto_005")) {
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Marker Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  return true;
              }
              return false;
          }
      }
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me either :v .Could it be that it fails because of the way I add them to the map?

Comment: I have tried the onMarkerClick method on a normal activity and it works fine. There needs to be a way to do the same on a fragment

Comment: try applicationContext() , maybe the context wasnt set properly

Comment: Tried but no results. Is there another method for an action to occur when clicking on a marker other than the setOnMarkerClickListener? The onMapClick method works perfectly for me but I can't get an action to happen on a marker with it